# Browser doesn't show changes on Vaadin Project - Using Windows

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, vaadin

None of my web browsers show the current changes on my vaadin project.

- vaadin project is deployed on tomcat
- I use tomact 6 and vaadin 6 in eclipse
- I tried to restart tomcat - no success
- I also tried to delete the cache of the browsers - no success
- I also set cookies="false" of my project context in the server.xml - no succes

This is my eclipse console:

```
Feb 21, 2015 9:46:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFORMATION: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: G:\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;G:/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/../jre/bin/server;G:/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/../jre/bin;G:/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;G:\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;G:\IsoBuster;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;G:\Calibre2\;G:\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;G:\Entwicklung\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.4.3\;G:\Entwicklung\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.4.3\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;G:\Entwicklung\eclipse;;.
Feb 21, 2015 9:46:26 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNUNG: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ProjectVaadin' did not find a matching property.
Feb 21, 2015 9:46:27 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFORMATION: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Feb 21, 2015 9:46:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMATION: Initialization processed in 444 ms
Feb 21, 2015 9:46:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFORMATION: Starting service Catalina
Feb 21, 2015 9:46:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFORMATION: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.43
Feb 21, 2015 9:46:27 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFORMATION: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Feb 21, 2015 9:46:27 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFORMATION: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Feb 21, 2015 9:46:27 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFORMATION: Jk running ID=0 time=0/16  config=null
Feb 21, 2015 9:46:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMATION: Server startup in 564 ms
Feb 21, 2015 9:46:32 PM com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet checkProductionMode
WARNUNG: 
=================================================================
Vaadin is running in DEBUG MODE.
Add productionMode=true to web.xml to disable debug features.
To show debug window, add ?debug to your application URL.
=================================================================
Feb 21, 2015 9:54:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFORMATION: Reloading Context with name [/ProjectVaadin] has started
Feb 21, 2015 9:54:42 PM com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet checkProductionMode
WARNUNG: 
=================================================================
Vaadin is running in DEBUG MODE.
Add productionMode=true to web.xml to disable debug features.
To show debug window, add ?debug to your application URL.
=================================================================
```

My Tomcat settings:

[image]

thanks for help

---

UPDATE1: I found out that i have to restart Eclipse to get i working but thats really annoying

---

SOLUTION: The problem is my operating system. Windows does lock files. So u need to tell tomcat that he has to unlock them. read this:

https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/BOOT/Avoiding+JAR+and+file+locking+under+Windows

After ive done those changes in the context.xml of my tomcat i only need to restart tomcat and all is working like it normally has to.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean by `show the current changes`. I'm going to assume that you modified some classes and the changes do not propagate. I had this issue several times with eclipse, and the solution for me was to 1) refresh (F5 or right click -> refresh) the entire project in eclipse + 2) right click -> clean in the server view.

Comment: if i add some widgets to my mainWindow, they arent shown in the browser - yeah ok thx. ill try out ur solutions

Comment: the 2nd solution (tomcat-> clean) worked one time. then i changed something in the code and tried it a second time and now i get the Error:

"Could not delete G:\Entwicklung\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\ProjectVaadin\WEB-INF\lib\vaadin-6.8.15.jar. May be locked by another process."

Its really annoying :(

Comment: Have you tried to add ?restartApplication to the URL? For example http://localhost:8080/MyApp/?restartApplication

Comment: yes ive tried this aswell. didnt work :/

Comment: Tomcat is using it. 1) stop tomcat, 2) refresh project, 3) clean tomcat. This works for me always with eclipse

Comment: ive tried it your way and i found out something: all of the browers present the current version unregularly. sometimes its working, sometimes it doesnt... programming makes no fun this way :/

Comment: It's not browser related, it's Eclipse related. Most likely how it publishes the resources towards Tomcat. Haven't figured out what exactly goes wrong, but I lost interest since I started working with Idea and I'm not sure how Netbeans works.

Answer (score 1):

Java Servlets are not like PHP, python etc. You must wait for deploying. Change something press in eclipse crtl+shift+s then wait and look console. 20sec-5min. you should see in console again something like:

```
lut 24, 2015 2:36:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/ProjectVaadin] is completed
```

then refresh web page.

You can too save all files (crtl+shift+s) press Crtl + F5 and check restart tomcat.

You can too use JRebel really nice tool for Eclipse.

PS.
BTW. don't use old Vaadin 6.

Comment: afaik vaadin doenst work with java servlets. and i found a solution for my problem. the thing is i use windows and windows does lock files. so u need to say tomcats that he has to unlock the files: read this: https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/BOOT/Avoiding+JAR+and+file+locking+under+Windows now i only have to restart tomcat (which takes 0,7 seconds) and i see the new changes in the browser right after the restart: ps: i need to learn vaadin 6 because my concern uses it. thx for your help

Comment: 0,7 seconds really nice and enough to comfort work.

You have to know really good Vaadin 6 now, because it have a lot of security holes. You can wrote secure app with Vaadon 6, but it needs high knowledge about that.